# Working out the amount of free dates in a given time period

Tags: php, mysql

I have a fun one for you. I have a database with the date columns free_from and free_until. What I need to find is the amount of days between now and 1 month today which are free. For example, if the current date was 2013/01/15 and the columns were as follows:

```
free_from | free_until
2013/01/12| 2013/01/17
2013/01/22| 2013/01/26
2013/01/29| 2013/02/04
2013/02/09| 2013/02/11
2013/02/14| 2013/02/17
2013/02/19| 2013/02/30
```

The answer would be 16
as 2 + 4 + 6 + 2 + 2 + 0 = 16

- The first row only starts counting at the 15th rather than the 12th
  since the 15th is the current date.
- The last row is discounted because none of the dates are within a
  month of the current date.
- The dates must be counted as it the `free_from` date is inclusive and
  the `free_until` date is exclusive.

I'm assuming `DATEDIFF()` will be used somewhere along the line, but I can't, for the life of me, work this one out.

Thanks for your time!

Edit: This is going into PHP mysql_query so that might restrict you a little concerning what you can do with MYSQL.

Comment: Can these records overlap? E.g. `2013/01/12-2013/01/17` and `2013/01/16-2013/01/21`.

Comment: Nope. I tried to include any strange cases in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @today = "2013-01-15";
SET @nextm = DATE_ADD(@today, INTERVAL 1 month);
SET @lastd = DATE_ADD(@nextm, INTERVAL 1 day);

SELECT 
 DATEDIFF(
   IF(@lastd> free_until, free_until, @lastd), 
   IF(@today > free_from, @today, free_from)
 )
FROM `test` 
WHERE free_until >= @today AND free_from < @nextm
```

That should work. At least for your test data. But what day is 2013/02/30? :-)

Dont forget to change @today = CURDATE();

Comment: I'll give that a try just now.
Haha! Fair point on the February date. I've not had my coffee yet :(

Comment: Sorry, just realised I'm being a total idiot here. The code has to be applicable to PHPs mysql_query() so this won't work. My fault. Should have specified. This gets an upvote anyway as it will be useful to others and is a very cool piece of code.

Comment: I take that back. I exchanged the variables for their values in the query to suit mysql_query and it works.

P.S You are God.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is something like:

```
WHERE free_until > CURDATE()
AND free_from < CURDATE() + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
```

That will get rid of any unnecessary rows. Then on the first row do in PHP:

```
date_diff(date(), free_until)
```

On the last row, do:

```
date_diff(free_from, strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayDate)) . "+1 month"))
```

Then on intermediate dates do:

```
date_diff(free_from, free_until)
```

Something to that effect, but this seems extremely clunky and convoluted...

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my mind... first do a:

```
SELECT a.free_from AS a_from, a.free_until AS a_until, b.free_from AS b_from
FROM availability a
INNER JOIN availability b ON b.free_from > a.free_until
ORDER BY a_from, b_from
```

This probably will return a set of rows where for each row interval you have next i.e. greater intervals. The results are ordered strategically. You can then wrap the results in a partial group by:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.free_from AS a_from, a.free_until AS a_until, b.free_from AS b_from
FROM availability a
INNER JOIN availability b ON b.free_from > a.free_until
ORDER BY a_from, b_from
) AS NextInterval
GROUP BY a_from, b_until
```

In the above query, add a DATE_DIFF clause (wrap it in `SUM()` if necessary):

```
DATE_DIFF(b_until, a_from)
```